Return two closest rows above and below a target value in Polars
I'm trying to figure out the most elegant way in Polars to find the two bracketing rows (first above and first below) a specific target.  Essentially the Min > 0 & the Max < 0.
data = {
    "strike": [5,10,15,20,25,30],
    "target": [16] * 6,
}

df = (pl.DataFrame(data)
        .with_columns(
            diff = pl.col('strike') - pl.col('target')))

shape: (6, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬──────┐
│ strike ┆ target ┆ diff │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---  │
│ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64  │
╞════════╪════════╪══════╡
│ 5      ┆ 16     ┆ -11  │
│ 10     ┆ 16     ┆ -6   │
│ 15     ┆ 16     ┆ -1   │
│ 20     ┆ 16     ┆ 4    │
│ 25     ┆ 16     ┆ 9    │
│ 30     ┆ 16     ┆ 14   │
└────────┴────────┴──────┘

This is what I'm trying to arrive at.
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬──────┐
│ strike ┆ target ┆ diff │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---  │
│ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64  │
╞════════╪════════╪══════╡
│ 15     ┆ 16     ┆ -1   │
│ 20     ┆ 16     ┆ 4    │
└────────┴────────┴──────┘

I am able to do it through two separate filter operations but I can't seem to string these together and would like to avoid having to vstack the two individual results back together into a single data frame if possible.
df1 = (pl.DataFrame(data)
        .with_columns(
            diff = pl.col('strike') - pl.col('target'))
        .filter((pl.col('diff') > 0)).min())

shape: (1, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬──────┐
│ strike ┆ target ┆ diff │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---  │
│ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64  │
╞════════╪════════╪══════╡
│ 20     ┆ 16     ┆ 4    │
└────────┴────────┴──────┘

df2 = (pl.DataFrame(data)
        .with_columns(
            diff = pl.col('strike') - pl.col('target'))
        .filter((pl.col('diff') < 0)).max())

shape: (1, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬──────┐
│ strike ┆ target ┆ diff │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---  │
│ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64  │
╞════════╪════════╪══════╡
│ 15     ┆ 16     ┆ -1   │
└────────┴────────┴──────┘



data = {"strike": [5,10,15,20,25,30]}

target = 16
diff = pl.col("strike") - target

(
    pl.DataFrame(data)
    # diff and target can be added as columns, but this is not actually needed
    # .with_columns(target=target, diff=diff)
    # filter for where the diff equals the min above 0, or the max below 0
    .filter(
        (diff == diff.filter(diff > 0).min()) |
        (diff == diff.filter(diff < 0).max())
    )
)
# shape: (2, 1)
# ┌────────┐
# │ strike │
# │ ---    │
# │ i64    │
# ╞════════╡
# │ 15     │
# │ 20     │
# └────────┘


This method is about 50% faster than the pl.concat method posted by roman

This can have different solutions depending on whether you have duplicates in your data, how you want to resolve it if you have it, and if your data is already sorted or not.
Following should work for any data:
df = df.with_columns(diff=pl.col.strike - pl.col.target)

pl.concat([
    df.filter(pl.col.diff > 0).bottom_k(1, by="diff"),
    df.filter(pl.col.diff < 0).top_k(1, by="diff")
])

shape: (2, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬──────┐
│ strike ┆ target ┆ diff │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---  │
│ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64  │
╞════════╪════════╪══════╡
│ 20     ┆ 16     ┆ 4    │
│ 15     ┆ 16     ┆ -1   │
└────────┴────────┴──────┘

Or, if you don't actually need diff column:
target = 16
d = pl.col.strike - target

pl.concat([
    df.filter(d > 0).bottom_k(1, by=d),
    df.filter(d < 0).top_k(1, by=d)
])


Your answer could be adapted to use .arg_min() / .arg_max() which give indexes to use with .get()
df.select(
   pl.all().get(
      pl.when(pl.col('diff') > 0).then('diff').arg_min()
        .append(pl.when(pl.col('diff') < 0).then('diff').arg_max())
   )
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬──────┐
│ strike ┆ target ┆ diff │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---  │
│ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64  │
╞════════╪════════╪══════╡
│ 20     ┆ 16     ┆ 4    │
│ 15     ┆ 16     ┆ -1   │
└────────┴────────┴──────┘


I was able to get this to work but is seems a little clunky and not as elegant as I was hoping for.
df3 = (pl.DataFrame(data)
        .with_columns(
            diff = pl.col('strike') - pl.col('target'))
        .with_columns(
            max_lt_zero = pl.when(pl.col('diff') < 0).then(pl.col('diff')).otherwise(None).max(),
            min_gt_zero = pl.when(pl.col('diff') > 0).then(pl.col('diff')).otherwise(None).min())
        .filter(
            pl.max_horizontal (
                pl.col('diff') == pl.col('max_lt_zero'),
                pl.col('diff') == pl.col('min_gt_zero')))
        .select(['strike', 'target', 'diff'])
)

shape: (2, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬──────┐
│ strike ┆ target ┆ diff │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---  │
│ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64  │
╞════════╪════════╪══════╡
│ 15     ┆ 16     ┆ -1   │
│ 20     ┆ 16     ┆ 4    │
└────────┴────────┴──────┘



